# Android ksoap2 web service gets me the XML description of WSDL?

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

I'm using ksoap2 to call a simple method but at response I get the XML description on web service? This method simply get username and password and returns user balance.

**My Code:**

```
public class FaraSMSActivity extends Activity {

private final String NAMESPACE = "http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM";
private final String URL = "http://farasms.com/webservice/v2.02.php?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSGETBalance__";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "WSGETBalance__";
private String TAG = "PGGURU";
private static String res;
Button b;
TextView tv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
              task.execute();
        }
    });        
}


public void getBalance() {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo usernamePI = new PropertyInfo();
    usernamePI.setName("username");
    usernamePI.setValue("faramobile");
    usernamePI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(usernamePI);

    PropertyInfo PasswordPI = new PropertyInfo();
    PasswordPI.setName("password");
    PasswordPI.setValue("09142168375");
    PasswordPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(PasswordPI);

    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        res = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("1111", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("2222", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
}




private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        getBalance();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        tv.setText(res);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        tv.setText("Connecting...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

}
```

}

using this line I can log the result :
   Log.e("2222", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

It show exactly the thing when I explore "farasms.com/webservice/v2.02.php?wsdl" using web browser!!!!

This is the result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM">
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
<xsd:complexType name="authentication">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="returnCode">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="msgid" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="message">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="fromNum" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="toNum" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="fullmessage">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="fromNum" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="toNum" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="returnCodes">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:returnCode[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="msgids">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="messages">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:message[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="fullmessages">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:fullmessage[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="WSGETBalanceRequest">
<part name="authentication" type="tns:authentication"/>
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSGETBalanceResponse">
<part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSGETBalance__Request">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSGETBalance__Response">
<part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSdoSendSMS1Request">
<part name="authentication" type="tns:authentication"/>
<part name="message" type="tns:message"/>
</message>
<message name="WSdoSendSMS1Response">
<part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSdoSendSMS3Request">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="from" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="to" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="msg" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSdoSendSMS3Response">
<part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSdoSendSMS4Request">
<part name="authentication" type="tns:authentication"/>
<part name="message" type="tns:fullmessage"/>
</message>
<message name="WSdoSendSMS4Response">
<part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSgetDeliveryRequest">
<part name="authentication" type="tns:authentication"/>
<part name="msgids" type="tns:msgids"/>
</message>
<message name="WSgetDeliveryResponse">
<part name="result" type="tns:returnCodes"/>
</message>
<message name="WSchangePasswordRequest">
<part name="authentication" type="tns:authentication"/>
<part name="newPassword" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSchangePasswordResponse">
<part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="WSgetMessagesRequest">
<part name="authentication" type="tns:authentication"/>
<part name="numRows" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="WSgetMessagesResponse">
<part name="result" type="tns:messages"/>
</message>
<message name="WSgetNewMessagesRequest">
<part name="authentication" type="tns:authentication"/>
</message>
<message name="WSgetNewMessagesResponse">
<part name="result" type="tns:messages"/>
</message>
<portType name="SMSSYSTEMPortType">
<operation name="WSGETBalance">
<documentation>WSGETBalance</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSGETBalanceRequest"/>
<output message="tns:WSGETBalanceResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="WSGETBalance__">
<documentation>WSGETBalance__</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSGETBalance__Request"/>
<output message="tns:WSGETBalance__Response"/>
</operation>
<operation name="WSdoSendSMS1">
<documentation>WSdoSendSMS1</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSdoSendSMS1Request"/>
<output message="tns:WSdoSendSMS1Response"/>
</operation>
<operation name="WSdoSendSMS3">
<documentation>WSdoSendSMS3</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSdoSendSMS3Request"/>
<output message="tns:WSdoSendSMS3Response"/>
</operation>
<operation name="WSdoSendSMS4">
<documentation>WSdoSendSMS4</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSdoSendSMS4Request"/>
<output message="tns:WSdoSendSMS4Response"/>
</operation>
<operation name="WSgetDelivery">
<documentation>WSgetDelivery</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSgetDeliveryRequest"/>
<output message="tns:WSgetDeliveryResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="WSchangePassword">
<documentation>WSchangePassword</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSchangePasswordRequest"/>
<output message="tns:WSchangePasswordResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="WSgetMessages">
<documentation>WSgetMessages</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSgetMessagesRequest"/>
<output message="tns:WSgetMessagesResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="WSgetNewMessages">
<documentation>WSgetNewMessages</documentation>
<input message="tns:WSgetNewMessagesRequest"/>
<output message="tns:WSgetNewMessagesResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="SMSSYSTEMBinding" type="tns:SMSSYSTEMPortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="WSGETBalance">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSGETBalance" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="WSGETBalance__">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSGETBalance__" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="WSdoSendSMS1">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSdoSendSMS1" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="WSdoSendSMS3">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSdoSendSMS3" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="WSdoSendSMS4">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSdoSendSMS4" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="WSgetDelivery">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSgetDelivery" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="WSchangePassword">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSchangePassword" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="WSgetMessages">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSgetMessages" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="WSgetNewMessages">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM#WSgetNewMessages" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="SMSSYSTEM">
<port name="SMSSYSTEMPort" binding="tns:SMSSYSTEMBinding">
<soap:address location="http://farasms.com/webservice/v2.02.php"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

What wrong am i doing ?

Comment: Why don't you log the res variable? Your method name is in your SOAP action, try `SOAP_ACTION = "http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM"`

Comment: No res !   It gets this error :     expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <definitions targetNamespace='http://farasms.com/SMSSYSTEM'>@2:457 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44f4f750)

Comment: It's my mistake, your Soap_action seems good. If you don't change Soap_Action your res is equal to your wsdl?

Comment: OK, I know it is equal to wsdl. I want to call the method and get the result. Why it returns WSDL? I mean, what is the mistake in my code? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after searching a lot, I found the reason. The correct URL is this :

```
private final String URL = "http://farasms.com/webservice/v2.02.php";
```

I pointed the URL to WSDL itself not the webservice!